# how to see sub-modules in EDK(XPS)

Tags: module, git-submodules, platform, xilinx

I have an EDK project,made by running a make file in Linux.
I can see the modules and their connections in EDK but the sub-modules are not visible.
I mean when i double click on a module , nothing happens and it isn't like ISE that we could see sub-modules.
what should i do?
thanks